# How do you manage your DojoX code?

Tags: javascript, version-control, dojo

How are you managing your usage of [DojoX](http://dojotoolkit.org/projects/dojox) code or widgets in a production application?

The [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) is comprised of Core, Dijit, and DojoX. As an incubator for new ideas to extend the toolkit, DojoX code and widgets are functional with varying degrees of instability.

DojoX Code like *[QueryReadStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/book-dojo/part-3-javascript-programming-dojo-and-dijit/using-dojo-data/available-stores/dojox-d)* (for fetching batches of data from the server) or widgets like *[Grid](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/docx-documentation-under-development/grid)* (for utilizing a user interface grid component) are not included in Core or Dijit. But they are functional enough to utilize in some cases, with the caveat "developer beware", because in future Toolkit versions the API or the component location in the source tree might change. Another catch is that you may have to tweak the DojoX component you are using for it to function properly in your environment, as there's not yet a high degree of robustness in the code.

So, how are you ensuring that as the DojoX components you use evolve, your application stays on a smooth track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

- Stick to one version of Dojo and use it consistently.
- Move modified code to your own namespace and include it from there.

  - Effectively it is a forking of an existing DojoX module. All code syncing and back porting is your responsibility.
  - Pay attention to the rest of Dojo — if it changes in such a way that it breaks your forked version, be ready to patch your module as well.
- Copy modified files somewhere and include/require them before the original file is required.

To illustrate the latter technique imagine that there is one file I want to patch located in dojox/charting/abc.js:

```
dojo.provide("dojox.charting.abc");
// the rest of the file
...
```

I can copy it to my directory as, say, my/patched_abc.js, and make it look like that:

```
dojo.provide("my.patched_abc");
// now I include the rest of the file with my modifications

dojo.provide("dojox.charting.abc");
// the rest of the file
...
```

In my code that uses dojox.charting I include it like that:

```
dojo.require("my.patched_abc");
// now I can include dojox.charting,
// which will use my patched dojox.charting.abc module

dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
// the rest of the file
...
```

Just be careful to avoid circular "require" statements.

This technique works very well for backports and minor customizations. If your changes are more extensive than that, you should consider writing your own module.

Answer (score 4):

This may be an obvious, but much more involved, solution ... but: Get involved! It actually is one of the best ways to familiarize yourself with the overall power of Dojo in one sitting, teaches a lot of good JS-foo, and ensures you have inside information as to the future of a particular module. Most of DojoX is community contributed, and aiming for stability and usefulness. The more people reviewing, testing, hacking on the code -- the more likely it is to succeed and become stable.

Regards,
Peter Higgins